Clone or use Time travel in Snowflake?
So if I clone my whole production DB daily, I can save a lot of money with Time Travel 90 days storage cost,  right?
Also I can utilize that clone DB in the test Data Warehouse environment with latest data, so Time Travel will become useless for me except something happened during the day, but we can still use the default 1 day retention fix unexpected errors during the day.
So am i missing anything here?
Thanks

Yes - you could do what you suggest. However,

You'd have to manage 90 databases and their associated RBAC (assuming you want the equivalent of 90 days time travel)
For "point in time" queries you'd need to identify the correct DB and query that, rather than just query a single DB using "time travel" SQL
If you want a cloned DB for testing then creating that clone when it's required, rather than creating a clone every day, on the off chance that it will be needed, seems to be more efficient

Only you can decide the cost/benefit of the two approaches.
If you are looking to reduce costs, I'd start by thinking about your processes and what's actually required to support them e.g.

Could you reduce time travel to 30 days or 14 days?
Would cloning the DB less frequently (e.g. at month end) be beneficial?

